# How to stream video from url and play in android?

Tags: android, android-videoview, android-video-player

I would like to stream video from url and play in android. I want to play that video like youtube video. like, stream some byte and start play video. and also streaming is continue in background.

How it's possible? I have try with Videoview and Medialplayer. but when video size is very large video can't play and disply blank screen.

Comment: See this [Stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8485413/videoview-for-large-video?rq=1). Here it is described in a good way.

Answer (score 3):

Try this code:

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent.setDataAndType(Uri.parse("http://www.yourvideo.mp4"), Req_code);
startActivityForResult(intent);
```